# Can no longer create stories in wit.ai

Tags: wit.ai

Since this morning (European time), it's no longer possible to create new `stories` on wit.ai for me.

I noticed different issues when trying as usual in my existing `apps`, so I created a very simple new `app` to test what was going on.

This test app is available at https://wit.ai/deepiksdev/testing/ . It contains 2 `stories` (Hello and Goodbye) with appropriate `intents`

Here is screenshot of the `app`, which should obviously work:

[App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqgGl.png)

This may be a temporary problem on the platform . I noticed that both `stories`are still in `Waiting for status check`status, but it's been a long time now. I have not seen any info on Twitter regarding this issue.

Anyone else facing the same issue ?

Comment: voting to close as this question is off-topic wrt stackoverflow. We can't tell you why another site is not working...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the availability of a 3th party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. The `stories` are now working, after a 3 hour delay.

This may be useful to know for newbies who may experience this issue and wonder why their code is not working. Wit.ai is sometimes slow to validate `stories`